# Is there a way to retrieve the client secret of an Azure AD application using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to retrieve the Client Secret from Azure AD Application as a plain text by using PowerShell?

I tried with the below commands, but it is returning only the type of the secret, not the actual value.

```
$objectID = "00000-00000-00000-00000"
$keyID = "00000-00000-00000-00000"
$secret = Get-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId $objectID | Where-Object {$_.KeyId -eq $keyID}
$secret
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** retrieve the value of created Client Secret in any way.

Explanation of [secretText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/passwordcredential?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties):

> The generated password value is only returned during the **initial POST
> request** to addPassword. There is no way to retrieve this password in
> the future.

The only way is [add new Client Secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadappcredential?view=azps-5.8.0) and store the new value securely.

```
$SecureStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
New-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId 1f89cf81-0146-4f4e-beae-2007d0668416 -Password $SecureStringPassword
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much for the info