Unable to Authorize AzureDevOps application to Azure Data Factory
I am trying 'Authorize' Azure DevOps to access Azure Data Factory.
We have created a Service Principal for ADO, but when I try to Authorize it when adding a Azure Powershell task I get the following error message:
Service connection with name Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription(xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx03) already exists. Only a user having Administrator/User role permissions on service connection Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription(8b78eeed-28c1-45ac-afbb-99148f842203) can see it.

I don't have the permissions to create any new App registrations. Is there a way around this issue
I am at the stage of New Azure service connection, and I'm now at the point of Authentication. Can you let me know how to obtain the Service Principal Id? and Service Principal key

I'm not able to create a secret, see below. But I thought i wouldn't need to as there is already a Service Principal created, or am I wrong


There is one other confusing thing where I'm getting the error, and that is because my service connection is included in Service Connections tab,see below. So, I thought I would be able to connect?
The Visual Stuido Subscription ending in 203 is my subscription

When I follow the instructions:

Step1: Contact your Project Admin and navigate to Project Settings ->
Service connections -> Select the Service Connection name: Visual
Studio Enterprise Subscription:

I am presented with the following screen

OK, I found the option to Add User, see below

When I search for my Visual Studio Enterprise it doesn't appear, see image. Does it mean it hasn't appeared

Even though it would appear I have permissions when I try to authorize I still get the following error:

The Service connection highlighted in Yellow is my Service connection, and you can see the project Data Engineering

When I attempt update 4 I get the following:



Service connection with name Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription(xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx03) already exists. Only a user having Administrator/User role permissions on service connection Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription(8b78eeed-28c1-45ac-afbb-99148f842203) can see it.

The error means that the service connection name already exists in the Azure DevOps.
Here are two methods to solve the issue:
Method1: You can contact the Administrator of the project to grant the User/Administrator role of the Service Connection. Then you can directly use the existing Service Connection.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Service connections
Method2: You can create a new ARM service connection. Then you can use it in the Azure PowerShell task.
From your description, you already have a service principal for Azure DevOps.
Here are the steps:
Step1: Navigate to Project Settings -> Service Connections and find the Azure Resource Manager Service Connection.
For example:

Step2: Select the Service principal (manual) and input all required information.
For example:

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Create Azure RM service principal (manual)
Update5:
I can reproduce the same issue now.
The cause of the issue is that the Service Connection is invalid.
When you open the service connection, it will show the following error:
Failed to create an app in Microsoft Entra. Error: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation in Microsoft Graph Ensure that the user has permissions to create a Microsoft Entra Application.

For example:

In this case, the existing service connection can not be recognized by the Azure Powershell task. When you create the service connection, it will show the service connection is already existing.
To solve the issue, you need to use the existing Service Principal to create a valid manual ARM Service connection.
Here are the steps:
You can navigate to the page: AAD -> APP Registrations -> Select the target Service Principal.

The Application (client) ID is the Service Principal Id.
The Directory (tenant) ID is the Tenant ID.
Then you can navigate to Certificates & secrets tab to create the Secret key. It can be used in the Service Principal Key.

Then you can use the new service connection in the Azure PowerShell task.

Hi @Kevin, I'm going through your suggestion now - I have updated the question. Can you let know what Service Principal Id I should be using

@Patterson I have updated my answer to share more details. You can check it. Feel free to let me know if you have any further questions.

I don't have the permissions to create a new client secret, see updated question. However, as there already a Service Principal, do I really need to create a new client secret?

@Patterson I can understand your requirement. But the client secret cannot retrieve/view it after creation. If you can contact admin to get the existing client secret, you can directly use it without creating a new one. This ticket has a detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67099027/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-client-secret-of-an-azure-ad-application-using-po

On the other hand, you can also consider contacting the Project Admin in Azure DevOps to grant the User/Administrator role of the Service Connection(Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription) to your user account. Then you can directly use the existing service connection without creating a new service connection.

Hi @Kevin, I think you're right. The best option would be to contact the project administrator

@Patterson Yes. Correct. Please do it. You can refer to the method1 in the answer to get the details about how to granting the permission to service connection.

Could you please explain the process for Project Admin to grant User/Administrator role of the Service Connection((Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription) to my user account - one more time please

@Patterson Sure. Please refer to the update2 in the answer. Feel free to let me know if it can help you.

Hi @Kevin, I have added just one last update to the question. Can you le me know if I'm correct?

@Patterson yes you are correct. I think you can try to select the existing service connection in the drop-down list of the task

On the other hand, If you can see the service connection, you can also check the role of your account and confirm if you can use it

Hi @Kevin, I wanted to go through your final suggestion before I update the ticket.

@Patterson First, you can try to directly select the service connection in the dropdown list of the Azure PowerShell task if you can see the existing service connection. If you are not able to see it, you can contact the project admin to grant the admin/user role to your account. Then you can check if you can select the existing service connection successfully.

@Patterson I have updated the answer to share how to find the service connection in azure powershell task. You can check it.

I just wanted to respond as you have been so kind with your time in helping me.  Due to circumstances I have not been able to review your suggestion as I had hoped. However, I will go through your suggested fix in the morning and let you know how I can on. In the meantime thank you

@Patterson Thanks for your kindly feedback. I will wait for your update.

I am back in the office. I have updated the question. I followed your guide but unfortunately I'm not presented with the same screen that you get.

@Patterson You can click the three dots near the Edit option of the page. Then you can see the Security option. Then you can set the permission after clicking the Security Option.

You can refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#set-service-connection-permissions

yep, I see it my bad.

No Problem. Please go ahead the steps.

@Patterson From your latest screenshot, I can see that your account already have the admin role. I think you can directly select the service connection in Azure PowerShell task. You can refer to the update3 in my answer.

I have updated the screenshot showing that I'm still unable to Authorize with my Visual Studio Account.

@Patterson When you click the Azure Subscription dropdown list of the Azure PowerShell task,  can you see the service connection name: Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription? Please select the name under the service connection level instead of Azure Subscription level.

You can also share what you can see in the Azure Subscription dropdown list of the Azure PowerShell task

I have shared what I see can in our Azure Subscription dropdown

@Patterson Can you confirm if the pipeline and the service connections are in the same project?

@Patterson You can refer to the update 4 in my answer. And try to use the method to input the service connection name. Please check if it can work for you.

I have updated the question showing my service connection and the project

I have tried your update 4, but no luck, please seen screen shot

@Patterson I can reproduce the same issue now! After checking all screenshots, I notice that the service connection itself is invalid. It shows the error in the service connection page. So the Azure PowerShell task can not read it. To solve this issue, you need to create a valid manual ARM service connection. This will help you solve the issue. I have updated the info in update 5. You may need to contact AAD admin to share the secret of the service principal with you.

are you therefore suggesting that I follow your update 5 and add that to the New Azure service connection as shown in my image?

SUCCESS!!! THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH!. Thank you for sticking with me. You are truly amazing. Thank you
